# Simple DOM Parser IF not working

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing

Can anyone tell why the second if statement pulling the soldby name wouldn't work properly?

What I want it to do is name pull the alt attribute from the image, if there is an image for the seller - which works. But if there isn't an image logo, there is a bold tag with the seller name which I want to be inserted in the same place in the array that the alt tag would be.

The HTML I am working with is: http:// amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B002UYSHMM

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

```
$item = array();

foreach ($html->find('div.resultsset table tbody.result tr') as $article) { 
  if ($article->find('span.price', 0)) {  
    // get retail  
    $item[$retail.$i++] = $article->find('span.price', 0)->plaintext;  
    // get soldby
    if ($article->find('ul.sellerInformation img', 0)) {
      $item[$soldby.$j++] = $article->find('ul.sellerInformation img', 0)->getAttribute('alt');
    } else {
      $item[$soldby.$j++] = $article->find('ul.sellerInformation li a b', 0)->plaintext;
    }
    $ret['SellerInfo'] = $item;
  }
}
```

Here is the array I get out of my code above:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [Retail] => $219.88 [SoldBy] => J&R Music and Computer World ) [1] => Array ( [Retail] => $234.21 [SoldBy] => PORTABLE GUY ) [2] => Array ( [Retail] => $235.73 [SoldBy] => The Price Pros ) [3] => Array ( [Retail] => $234.74 [SoldBy] => GizmosForLife ) [4] => Array ( [Retail] => $230.00 [SoldBy] => ) [5] => Array ( [Retail] => $198.73 [SoldBy] => ) [6] => Array ( [Retail] => $240.72 [SoldBy] => ) [7] => Array ( [Retail] => $248.99 [SoldBy] => onSale ) )
```

You can see that it is missing SoldBy for:

STEPHS GREAT BOOK TREASURES

Diakonos23

OptimumHouse

Comment: You might want to include the HTML in question, my telepathic skill is used up for today …

Comment: Oops!  Sorry I added a link above.  It is the amazon offer listing page.

Comment: @GolezTrol Sorry that's my bad, the question was edited by the OP while I was editing to fix the code spacing, and my edit ate his. Now fixed.

Comment: Looking at the html I don't see something that would match `li a b`

Comment: This matches `li a b`: STEPHS GREAT BOOK TREASURES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
foreach($html->find('div.resultsset table tbody.result tr') as $article) { 
if($article->find('span.price', 0)) {  
// get retail  
$item['Retail'] = $article->find('span.price', 0)->plaintext;  
// get soldby  
if($article->find('img', 0)->getAttribute('alt') <> '') {
$item['SoldBy'] = $article->find('img', 0)->getAttribute('alt'); }
else {$item['SoldBy'] = $article->find('ul.sellerInformation li a b', 0)->plaintext;}
$ret[] = $item; 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from it being wise not to use the `b`, your selectors are different. The first directly selects an image in the list, while the second requires a bold tag inside a link, inside a list item.

Comment: I understand it might be unwise to use the b but I have no choice in this case.  The selectors both work if I use them seperatly but inside the IF statement they do not work when there is not an image present.  It just prints blank.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
if (count($article->find('span.price'))) {
```

and

```
if (count($article->find('ul.sellerInformation img'))) {
```

?

Comment: I haven't.  How could I implement count into the code?  I am not sure what that would do?  I tried using that in place of my code but no change.  Still just blank where there is text for the seller name instead of an image.